# Slideshow no run on .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, razor

the code below should display a slideshow in a cshtml file with the sources below, but the slideshow is not displayed but a list of values is printed in the html. How can I display an automatic slideshow

**index.cshtml**

```
@using TotemDisplayMulti.ViewModels;@model MultiDisplayVM@ {
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

< script >
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);
keepMoving();
function plusSlides(n) {
    interrupt();
    console.log("plusSlides: " + n);
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    console.log("currentSlide: " + n);
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    console.log("currentSlide: " + n);

    const element = document.querySelector(".dots");
    const count = element.querySelectorAll(".dot").length;
    slideIndex = slideIndex >= count ? 0 : slideIndex;
    console.log(slideIndex, count);
    element.scrollTo({
        left: slideIndex * 300
    });
}

window.userInterrupt = false;

function interrupt() {
    window.userInterrupt = true;
}

function keepMoving() {
    console.log("Sono in keep modvien: " + n);
    const interval = setInterval(() = >{
        if (window.userInterrupt) clearInterval(interval);
        else plusSlides(1);
    },
    5000);
}

< /script>
<body onload="keepMoving();">

    <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/ / www.w3schools.com / w3css / 4 / w3.css ">
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .nav-container {
                position: relative;
                width: 300px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 300px;
            }

            .dots {
                font-size: 0;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .prev,
            .next {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                background: royalblue;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .prev {
                left: -40px;
            }

            .next {
                right: -40px;
            }
        </style>
        <div style="display: grid;
grid - template - columns: auto auto auto;
background - color: white;
padding: 10px;
">
            <div style="background - color: white;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
padding: 20px;
text - align: center;
">
                <img style="vertical - align: middle;
margin - top: 50px " src="@Url.Content("~/sidebar.png")" alt="sidebar ">
            </div>
            <div style="background - color: white;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
padding: 20px;
text - align: center;
">
                <img style="vertical - align: middle;
margin - top: 50px " src="@Url.Content("~/scam.jpg")" alt="scamlogo " width="80 " height="60 "> Il nostro impegno per la sostenibilità
                <p></p>
                <div>
                    <div id="first - div " style="float - left;
width: 180px;
display: inline - block;
margin - right: 10px;
border: 2px solid blue;
border - radius: 25px;
background - color: orange ">
                        <div style="margin - top: 30px;
background - color: orange ">
                            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem;
background - color: orange;
width: 120px ">
                                <div class="card - body ">
                                    <img style="margin - left: 20px;
margin - top: 5px " src="@Url.Content("~/gauge.png")" alt="scamlogo " width="40 " height="40 ">
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px "><b>Potenz Attuale</b></h5>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">11.77,56 KW</p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">680 KW installati</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="second - div " style="float - left;
width: 180px;
display: inline - block;
margin - right: 10px;
border: 2px solid blue;
border - radius: 25px;
background - color: green ">
                        <div style="margin - top: 30px;
background - color: green ">
                            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem;
background - color: green;
width: 120px ">
                                <div class="card - body ">
                                    <img style="margin - left: 20px;
margin - top: 5px " src="@Url.Content("~/gauge.png")" alt="scamlogo " width="40 " height="40 ">
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px "><b>Potenz Attuale</b></h5>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">11.77,56 KW</p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">680 KW installati</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="third - div " style="float - left;
width: 180px;
display: inline - block;
margin - right: 10px;
border: 2px solid blue;
border - radius: 25px;
background - color: blue ">
                        <div style="margin - top: 30px;
background - color: blue ">
                            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem;
background - color: blue;
width: 120px ">
                                <div class="card - body ">
                                    <img style="margin - left: 20px;
margin - top: 5px " src="@Url.Content("~/gauge.png")" alt="scamlogo " width="40 " height="40 ">
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px;
font - size: 13 "><b>Energia</b></h5>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">@Model.ProduzioneTotale KW</p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: white;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">680 KW installati</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="four - div " style="float - left;
width: 180px;
display: inline - block;
margin - right: 10px;
border: 2px solid blue;
border - radius: 25px;
background - color: white ">
                        <div style="margin - top: 30px;
background - color: white;
width: 180px ">
                            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem;
background - color: white;
width: 120px ">
                                <div class="card - body ">
                                    <img style="margin - left: 20px;
margin - top: 5px " src="@Url.Content("~/foggy.png")" alt="scamlogo " width="40 " height="40 ">
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px "><b>@Html.Raw(Model.City)</b></h5>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">11.77,56 KW</p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="card - text " style="margin - left: 20px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">680 KW installati</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="w3 - content w3 - display - container ">
                        <article class="dot - container ">

                            <div class="dots ">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.listaValori)
                                {
                                <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(@item.number)">
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px "><b>@item.City</b></h5>


                                    Data Attivazione
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px "><b>@item.dataAttivazione.Remove(0, 11)</b></h5>
                                    Autoconsumo
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">Delta emissione<b>@item.DeltaEnergeticoImmissioneNelPeriodo</b></h5>@item.EnergiaProdotta
                                    Prestazione mese
                                    <h5 class="card - title " style="margin - left: 15px;
color: blue;
margin - left: 10px;
margin - top: 20px ">Delta emissione<b>@item.EnergiaAttuale</b> | </h5>@item.EnergiaProdotta? @item.EnergiaProdotta: "0 " mese


                                </span>
                                }


                            </div>


                        </article>
                    </div>


                    <div style="margin - top: 50px ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div style="display: inline - block;
width: 20 % ;
height: 50 % ;
position: relative;
margin: -2px;
">
                                <div class="card " style="background - color: white ">
                                    <div class="card - body ">
                                        <div style="color: grey ">Emissioni evitate</div>

                                        <div style="color: blue ">@Html.Raw(Model.CO2)</div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div style="display: inline - block;
width: 20 % ;
height: 50 % ;
position: relative;
margin: -2px;
">
                                <div class="card " style="background - color: white ">
                                    <div class="card - body ">
                                        <div style="color: grey ">Alberi equivalenti</div>

                                        <div style="color: blue ">@Html.Raw(Model.albertiTrapiantati)</div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: inline - block;
width: 20 % ;
height: 50 % ;
position: relative;
margin: -2px;
">
                                <div class="card " style="background - color: white ">
                                    <div class="card - body ">
                                        <div style="color: grey ">Equivalente petroilio</div>

                                        <div style="color: blue ">@Html.Raw(Model.Tep)</div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: inline - block;
width: 20 % ;
height: 50 % ;
position: relative;
margin: -2px;
">
                                <div class="card " style="background - color: white ">
                                    <div class="card - body ">
                                        <div style="color: grey ">Produzione Totale</div>

                                        <div style="color: blue ">@Html.Raw(Model.ProduzioneTotale_STR)</div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>"
```

Comment: There are way too many spaces in your code. Did you somehow introduce those when posting here or are they really in there? E.g. at the top you have `< script >` where it should say `<script>`, and also in a whole bunch of other places.